# How to make in app purchase work with tvOS beta 2?

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit, tvos

I am working on an tvOS app which is linked (with the same App ID) to an iOS app where in app purchase is fully functional, and I am using the same implementation as for the iOS app.

I am using a development apple TV, not just the simulator.

My sandbox tester account is not recognized by the Apple TV and my productsRequest doesn't get any answer.

Is there something specific to do with StoreKit on tvOS ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer. In app purchases actually work with beta 2 and the developer Apple TV.

In my case I just needed to declare my productRequest as a property in my ViewController and not just in my `buyProduct()` method like in the iOS version.

`var productRequest = SKProductsRequest()`

Comment: Perfect. This is likely related to the same issue Obj-C devs were seeing where they had to retain the SKProductsRequest before starting it. In Swift the solution is to assign it to a var so it doesn't go away.

Comment: do you have sign-up/sign-in flow in your tvOS app or you just link the iOS app and tvOS app through websocket service? I heard that if my tvOS app didn't have that flow, apple would reject the in-app purchase in my tvOS, is it true?